# Why is this Hive code returning 0 results?

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata, hiveql

```
select * 
FROM prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_dn A JOIN 
     prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_rw B
     ON A.OPPORTUNITYID  = B.SFDC_ID LEFT JOIN
     prd_raw_sf.sf_si_accounts_mapping C
     ON TRIM(UPPER(A.ACCOUNT_NAME)) = TRIM(UPPER(C.sfdc_account_name))
WHERE C.sfdc_account_name IS NULL
and C.Billing_Client in ('CL.00000:')
```

It returns the necessary results when I query till "WHERE C.sfdc_account_name IS NULL". However, if I add the last line... "and C.Billing_Client in ('CL.00000:')", it just returns 0 result. Please help!

Comment: Why?  Because either the `JOIN` or `WHERE` clause filters out all results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I speculate that you intend:

```
SELECT * 
FROM prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_dn od JOIN 
     prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_rw orw
     ON od.OPPORTUNITYID = orw.SFDC_ID LEFT JOIN
     prd_raw_sf.sf_si_accounts_mapping am
     ON TRIM(UPPER(od.ACCOUNT_NAME)) = TRIM(UPPER(ord.sfdc_account_name)) AND
        am.Billing_Client in ('CL.00000:')
WHERE am.sfdc_account_name IS NULL;
```

It is impossible for the account name to be `NULL` after the `LEFT JOIN` and for the `Billing_Client` to be anything *other* than `NULL`.  That is because the account name is used as a `JOIN` key, so `NULL` does not match.  The `NULL` value indicates no match, so all other columns from the table are `NULL`.

Note that I also fixed the table aliases so they are meaningful rather than arbitrary letters.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff ... That was helpful